# About finding the number of $k$-ary sequences of length $n$

Tags: combinatorics

> If $X = \{1, 2, ..., 100\}$ and $S = \{(a, b, c) : a, b, c \in X,  a < b,  a < c\}$, find $|S|$.

For a start, to form a sequence $abc$ we select $a$ from $X$, then $b$ from $X$ and then $c$ from $X$. There are $100$ choices for $a$ denoted $k$, $100 - k$ choices for $b$ and $100 - k$ choices for $c$. So there must be $100(100 - k)^2$ sequences of the form $(abc) \in S$.

Why is what's written above incorrect?

Comment: You need to sum over all possible k.

Comment: I am trying to get the first part of the problem correct and so far nothing.

Comment: What is the first part if not finding $|S|$?

Comment: I am supposed to use Multiplication Principle first, then Addition Principle.

Comment: Anurag's answer elaborates on what my hint was about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have $100$ choices for $a$. In fact you have only $99$ choices because $a \neq 100$ (otherwise there is no value left for $b$ and $c$).

Now if $a=k$, then all the values from $\{k+1, k+2, \ldots , 100\}$ are admissible for $b$ and $c$ (assuming that they can be equal as well). Thus for each choice of $a$ you have $(100-k)^2$ choices for the pair $(b,c)$ (this is where you have used multiplication). Thus by the addition principle
$$|S|=\sum_{k=1}^{99}(100-k)^2=\frac{1}{6}(99)(99+1)(2(99)+1)=328350.$$